# Função para ativar e desativar Listener

Tags: python, tkinter

Boa Tarde gente, tenho o seguinte codigo que até funciona perfeitamente. 
Porém tenho um erro, quando eu clico no "bt1" (botao de iniciar)
o meu programa trava. Porém la no console ele ta funcionando.
Só o executavel trava.
Alguém me ajuda achar uma solução pra isso ?
e seria possivel eu criar uma função só tanto pra ativar quanto desativar o 
listener ? Agradeço

Edit: Bom, descobri que se eu coloco o listener.join() antes do mainloop(),
ele funciona, printa todas teclas no console, mas a janela do tk nao abre.
Mas se eu coloco o mainloop() antes, a jenala abre, mas nao printa tecla nenhuma..

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial 

def press(key):
    keyd = str(key)
    keyd = keyd.replace("'","")
    if (keyd == "Key.space" or keyd== "Key.shift_r" or keyd=="Key.ctrl_l" or 
    keyd=="Key.caps_lock" or keyd == "Key.right" or keyd == "Key.left" 
    or keyd == "Key.right" or keyd == "Key.ctrl_r" or keyd== 'Key.backspace'
    or keyd == 'Key.shift' or keyd == 'Key.tab' or keyd == 'Key.cmd'):
        keyd = ""
    with open('KeyTester.docx', "a") as op:
        op.write(keyd + "\n")
    print(keyd)

def ena():
    with Listener(on_press=press) as l:
        l.join()
def dis():
    with Listener(on_press=press) as l:
        l.stop()

window = Tk()
bt1 = Button(window, text="Iniciar Atividade", command=ena).grid()
bt2 = Button(window, text="Parar Atividade", command=dis).grid()
btRel = Button(window, text="Verificar Relatório").grid()</code>

window.title('KeyBLG 1.0')
window.geometry("300x200+1200+400")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

para criar a função de ativar e desativar o listener, você poderia colocar a def press dentro de uma outra função com um if else e ja que está usando tkinter atrelar a um botão pra fazer um altenador. tambem poderia fazer na própria press que quando uma certa combinação de teclas é apertada ele pararia a de fazer certa parte da função mas continuava ativo e quando a combinação fosse pressionada novamente a função seria reativada totalmente.

esse video pode te dar umas novas ideias de uso do listener:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_dfv5DLCGI

Comment: eu fiz o que você disse, o erro permanece o mesmo, quando eu clico em iniciar o programa trava, mas no console ele printa as teclas que to apertando.
 Descobri o porque isso está acontecendo mais não sei como resolver.
Ao meu ver, pareçe quando quando eu inicio o Listener
 com listener.join() , window.mainloop() não pode ta ativo.
pois se eu colocar o listener.join() antes do window.mainloop() ele funciona, mas a janela do tkinter nao aparece.
e se eu coloco o listener.join() depois do mainloop(), a janela abre, mas o listener nao registra nada.

Comment: nas funções ena() e dis() era para em ambar estar on_press=press?

Comment: Não muda nada, 
se eu coloco o listener.join() antes do mainloop(), ele funciona, printa todas teclas no console, mas a janela do tk nao abre. Mas se eu coloco o mainloop() antes, a jenala abre, mas nao printa tecla nenhuma..

Comment: qual a intenção do programa?

Comment: usar .bind do tkinter ñ server?